# How to connect to a VPC project

Tags: google-bigquery, google-vpc

I am new to BigQuery and i'm trying to understand how VPC access works for BigQuery projects. I have a BigQuery project that imports data from several other BigQuery projects (no VPC but same organisation). I also need to connect to a project that is in a VPC network (still same organisation).

The only way that I can read this VPC project is to

1. Be a Gsuite member
2. Connect to the organisation VPN
3. Open the cloud console trough a proxy
4. I can only read the project and write queries if i'm in the VPC project itself
5. I want to be able to read and write queries for the VPC project in my own project
6. I want to be able to schedule data imports on daily aggregated data from the VPC project into my project.

Will this be possible if I add my project to a service perimeter and get access trough a perimeter bridge? What sort of access do I need to set up in order to read and import VPC project data directly in my project?

Answer (score 0):

In this [page](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products#bigquery) you can find the `BigQuery` limitations when using `VPC`. Basically, if you want to use a service account to access a BigQuery instance protected by a service perimeter you must access from within the perimeter.

> - VPC Service Controls does not support copying BigQuery resources protected by a service perimeter to another organization. Access
>     levels do not enable you to copy across organizations.
> - To copy protected BigQuery resources to another organization, download the dataset (for example, as a CSV file), and then upload
>     that file to the other organization.
> - The BigQuery Data Transfer Service is supported only for the following services:
>
>   - Campaign Manager
>   - Google Ad Manager
>   - Google Ads
>   - Google Cloud Storage
>   - Google Merchant Center
>   - Google Play
>   - YouTube
> - The BigQuery Classic Web UI is not supported. A BigQuery instance protected by a service perimeter cannot be accessed with the BigQuery
>     Classic Web UI.
> - The third-party ODBC driver for BigQuery cannot currently be used with the restricted VIP.
> - BigQuery audit log records do not always include all resources that were used when a request is made, due to the service internally
>     processing access to multiple resources.
> - When using a service account to access a BigQuery instance protected by a service perimeter, the BigQuery job must be run within a project
>     inside the perimeter. By default, the BigQuery client libraries will
>     run jobs within the service account or user's project, causing the
>     query to be rejected by VPC Service Controls.